# The derivative of a polynomial obtained with numpy.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit() gives an incorrect value

Tags: python, numpy, derivative

I am obtaining a first degree polynomial (a line) from a set of points, and using line.deriv() to get the derivative. I expect de derivative to be the coefficient[1], but instead I get a different number

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [0.1, 0.3, 0.6]

line = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1)
print(line)
print(line.deriv())
```

Gives back:

```
poly([0.33333333 0.25      ])
poly([0.25])
```

Which is correct.
But if I add another point

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [0.1, 0.3, 0.6, 0.7]

line = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1)
print(line)
print(line.deriv())
```

Gives back:

```
poly([0.425 0.315])
poly([0.21])
```

Which seems wrong

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see are the coefficients in the *scaled domain*, see last paragraph of the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.polynomials.html#transition-guide):

> Note that the coefficients are given in the scaled domain defined by
> the linear mapping between the window and domain. `convert` can be used
> to get the coefficients in the unscaled data domain.

So to get the "usual" coefficients you need to do

```
print(line.convert().coef)
```

which gives `[-0.1   0.21]` as expected.

Btw, IPython shows a nice rich output of `line`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the answer by Stef, tells you that the coefficients are scaled using a linear mapping. You can have look at the source code of `deriv`.
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/8cec82012694571156e8d7696307c848a7603b4e/numpy/polynomial/_polybase.py#L882

`off, scl = self.mapparms()`

`off` and `scl` represent the offset and scaling respectively.

So if you want to have the behaviour you except, you must provide a window equal to the domain as follows:

```
>>> line = np.polynomial.polynomial.Polynomial.fit(x, y, 1, domain [-1,1],window=[-1,1])
>>> line
Polynomial([-0.1 ,  0.21], domain=[-1.,  1.], window=[-1.,  1.], symbol='x')
>>> line.deriv()
Polynomial([0.21], domain=[-1.,  1.], window=[-1.,  1.], symbol='x')
```